# Getting INVALID_SESSION_ID on REST Api call in C#

Tags: rest-api, authentication, c#

`"[{\"message\":\"Session expired or invalid\",\"errorCode\":\"INVALID_SESSION_ID\"}]"`

I reviewed the other questions posted but no answers helped.
I am using grant type `"password"`.

On my authenticate call I get this back *(values changed to protect the innocent)*:

```
{
  "access_token": "00BLARDEBLAR..",
  "instance_url": "https://blar.salesforce.com",
  "id": "https://test.salesforce.com/id/00BLAH/00BLHABLHA",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "issued_at": "1611009241343",
  "signature": "A99SigAmature"
}
```

Here's how i'm trying to use it:

```
string response = message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(response);

// I have confirmed these values match the response.
string AuthToken = (string)obj["access_token"];
string ServiceUrl = (string)obj["instance_url"];

// versionEndpoint = "/services/data/v50.0"
string EndPointURL = ServiceUrl + login.versionEndpoint;

content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"Authorization", "Bearer " + AuthToken},
    {"X-PrettyPrint", "1"}
});

message = Client.PostAsync(EndPointURL + "/sobjects/", content).Result;
response = message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

And this is when I get back:

`"[{\"message\":\"Session expired or invalid\",\"errorCode\":\"INVALID_SESSION_ID\"}]"`

What am I missing?
TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're calling it, you're putting data into the body. You need to use the `Headers` attribute instead.

```
content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
{ // Whatever body elements you need goes here
});
content.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = "Bearer " + AuthToken;
```

See also [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52794526/2132791), which basically says the same thing.

Comment: Ah.  Ok thanks. This makes sense.  But now it's telling me `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects.'`  I'll poke around a bit.  `content` is defined as `HttpContent`

Comment: @flashsplat Looks like `DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization` is the correct property here. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14628278/2132791) on [so].

Comment: Boom!  That got me on the right track.  Thank you. Got one more error after that saying I couldn't POST, so I switched to GET and now i'm cookin'!  Thanks again!

Comment: It won't let me upvote your answer do to my rep :(.

Comment: @flashsplat You're welcome. I edited in the answer.

Comment: I have come back almost 3 years later to finally upvote your answer.  Thanks again.

Comment: @flashsplat Thanks! Glad I was able to help in a moment of need.